# CSS for the gridview

Tags: asp.net

i want a css that handle all property of a grid view....like:

```
    width: 100px;
height:2px; 

background-color:blue;
overflow:hidden;
```

after use this css ....i can not fix the gridview column width.....selected column color....
i want to know how to control all property of gridview from the css.......like column width,height,

```
COLUMN VALUE

aaa

bbbbb

ddddddddddd


ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

i want a css that handle this column ...and set widht 100px .....output liek:

```
COLUMN VALUE

    aaa

    bbbb
    b

    ddd
    ddd
    ddd
    dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by a grid-view, but what I use to accomplishm thumbnails appearing in a table-like view without actually use table.

```
div.entry-shopbox {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 340px;
    margin:0 12px 0 4px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    over-flow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;

    }
```

Werid padding all around because for IE-6

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css for columns and Set the property ItemStyle-CssClass

Comment: i use it on column ....but i can not get what i need .How to scroll up on column like my question input's output